Is it possible to add "thumb" image to a hyperlink?
I use Mal's e-commerce for the shopping cart on my website. Typically I use <form> code for the "Add to Cart" button which allows a thumbnail image to be included on the shopping cart page. The https://www.example.com/thumbnail-image/... part of the "thumbnail.jpg" URL is parked on Mal's website.
I need to instead use a hyperlink "Add to Cart" on one of my pages, but in doing so I'm not able to include the <input name="thumb"...> line of code. I'm not well-versed with coding so I might not be phrasing this question correctly (and hope I'm not being too confusing), but is there a way to add a thumbnail ("thumb") command to the line of hyperlink I'm wanting to use?
This is the code I usually use:
<form action="https://www.example.com/cf/add.cfm" method="post">
<input name="userid" type="hidden" value="00000000">
<input name="product" type="hidden" value="Acme Widget">
<input name="price" type="hidden" value="30.00">
<input name="thumb" value="thumbnail.jpg" type="hidden">
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="https://mywebsite.com/">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>

This is the hyperlink code I would like to use and include a thumbnail (if possible):
<a href="https://www.example.com/cf/add.cfm?userid=00000000&return=https://www.example.com.com/&product=Acme+Widget&price=30.00">Add to Cart</a>


short answer would be probably yes. long answer would be long. Not sure what would be your issue here. Is it difficulties with making the thumbnail? is it getting the main image?

Hi, sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking so I might miss the mark with my answer, but I sell products and want a thumbnail image of the product to still be visible on the shopping cart page when the hyperlink is used.

You could wrap the anchor tag around an img tag, like so <a href="..."><img src="..."/></a> where the img tag's src will point to your thumbnail.

Actually, I was able to figure it out and it turned out being pretty simple. I just added &thumb=thumbnail.jpg and that did the trick.

I was able to figure it out and it turned out being pretty simple. I just added &thumb=thumbnail.jpg at the end of the hyperlink and that did the trick.
